# ggplot fill property changes scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple dataframe and using ggplot to create a bar graph using the code:

```
ggplot(data=data_cases,aes(x = k,y = val)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom = "bar") +
  scale_x_discrete(name="Type",
                   labels=c('A&R','A&E','C&E'))
```

This code generates the desired result. However when i add a fill property to color the portions of the graph, it changes the y scale. In the image below, the picture on the left has the correct scale, the one on the right is what is produced if the fill property is set (`ggplot(data=data_cases,aes(x = k,y = val, fill=state))`)

[image: ggplot output]

Data:

```
"k","state","val"
"A&C","SA ",3
"C&E","SA ",2
"A&C","NSW",29
"A&E","NSW",10
"C&E","NSW",11
"C&E","NT ",1
"A&C","WA ",3
"A&E","WA ",1
"C&E","WA ",4
"A&C","VIC",24
"A&E","VIC",1
"C&E","VIC",15
"A&C","QLD",7
"A&E","QLD",2
"C&E","QLD",17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because this second chart is showing the number of cases per state, e.g. almost 30 for NSW with type A&R. Each bar is starting from 0.

If you want to be like the original then all the bars should be stacked on top of each other: use `position='stack'`

```
ggplot(data=data_cases,aes(x = k,y = val)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom = "bar", position="stack") + # <---
  scale_x_discrete(name="Type",
                   labels=c('A&R','A&E','C&E'))
```

[image]

ggplot has a bunch of positions like this. ?position_dodge, ?position_fill, ?position_stack, ?position_identity, ...

Comment: This solved the problem, Thanks. I get what went wrong but it seems a bit fiddly compared to other languages...

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ it is not so fiddly to add `, position="stack"`. How would other languages do it with less characters? Sometimes you want a bar chart to stack and sometimes you don't. Perhaps the other languages do not give you the option.

Answer (score 1):

can also use `geom_col`

```
ggplot(df, aes(k, val, fill = state)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]